# Gulp postcss lost grid system - framework

Tags: sass, grid, gulp, postcss

I have got a gulp file with [lost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lost) package installed however it seems that the css is not compiled properly when running my task.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true }),
    browsersync = require('browser-sync'),
    del = require('del'),
    config = require('./config.js')(),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    size = require('gulp-size'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    deporder = require('gulp-deporder'),
    stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    lost = require('lost'),
    minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
```

My gulp task is the following:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {

  var processors = [
    lost(),
    autoprefixer({browsers:['last 2 versions']})
  ];
  return gulp.src(styles.in)
      .pipe($.plumber())
      .pipe(postcss(processors))
      .pipe($.sass(styles.sassOpt))
      .pipe($.size({ title: 'styles In Size' }))
      .pipe($.size({ title: 'styles Out Size' }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(styles.out))
      .pipe(browsersync.reload({ stream: true }));
  log('-> Compile SASS Styles')
});
```

Help would be much appreciated,
Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit:**
The CSS output is not what is expected.
For example the CSS is rendered as:
    .grid-one
        lost-utility: clearfix
        with: 100%
    div
        lost-column: 1/6

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't explain the problem.  Is there an error?  What is the error?  Do you get a different output than you expected?  Does it launch nuclear missiles?

Comment: Apologies for not being precise, the calc() functions are not being rendered.
When I try to use the lost functions
    .column
        lost-column: 1/4

the Sass then CSS is rendered like that:
.column {
  lost-column: 1/4;}

Comment: So then your question has nothing to do with Sass?  Because Sass has nothing to do with the output being generated wrong (feeding it an ordinary CSS file would have the same results).

Comment: I don't know where the error lies, the sass is being generated into the right css but not the lost functions

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake my postcss task was watching a .sass file rather than a .css ...